# ORA-01866 with JDeveloper 10.1.3.4

Tags: java, oracle, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I'm running an application with ADF in JDeveloper 10.1.3.4.

When an Application Module is created, I get an exception with the error code mentioned in the title: "ORA-01866 the datetime class is invalid". It has *absolutely* nothing to do with code, I can assure you that. It only happens on my computer, there are other computers where this problem does not appear, same code and all. After the application module (BC4J) is created, everything works fine. It's very weird. To strengthen my point, in one part of the Application I create a new Thread (since I want to execute code in background in my web page), so I create a new application module, and here the exception appears again.

I'm running Windows XP with Service Pack 3. Java version is the one that comes with this version of JDeveloper. java.exe -version yields:

> java version "1.5.0_06"
>
> Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_06-b05)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_06-b05, mixed mode)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the solution suggested in this [thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=370167) on Oracle's forum:

- In the system registry, go to *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/ControlSet001/Controls/TimeZoneInformation*
- Remove the `DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet` property, or set it to `0`.